# Using Bootstrap and Foundation (jQuery part) in same page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation in one of my projects, now I want to use some components from Twitter Bootstrap, can I do this? If so how?

Comment: Which components? And I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use both. It all depends on how your project is structured. You  need to be more specific.

Comment: For example I want to use FuelUX components what I should take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as I understand it both bootstrap and foundation are fairly similar. But anyways here is a comparison and some things I would personally be concerned about.

**Some similarities:**

- Both have an option to download a stand-alone css file.
- Both have the option to customize the css file
- They both have a set of JavaScript plugins
- They are both built to be responsive
- Both have an Icon library
- They both use jQuery

**Some Differences:**

- Bootstrap supports less (there is third party support for sass using
  rails) [SEE HERE](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)
- Foundation supports SASS
- The markup for the controls is different
- The look and feel is different

**Some things to Consider:**

- There is a possibility of conflicting classes and styles when using
  both. This could also affect the JavaScript components as they are
  both dependent on those classes.
- In my opinion I feel like you should be able to use both without much
  conflict. My biggest concern would be
  difference in markup and possibility of conflicting classes as both
  use somewhat generic class names.

In the end I guess it comes down more to architecture and preference. I personally prefer Foundation because of its stand-alone SASS support. But on the other hand I think Bootstrap does a better job with the markup.

Comment: In the other hand I take Bootstrap because it has a lot of plugins and Foundation has not :-(